# magento 2 run comand and error showing it

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, cli, permissions, command

when I have run **upgrade command** or run **deploy command** and  below type error coming it

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Error:

```
Path "." cannot be used with directory "home/public_html/app/etc/"
```

and my frontend this type error coming it

```
main.CRITICAL: Path "." cannot be used with directory "/home/public_html/pub/static/
 Path \".\" cannot be used with directory \"/home/public_html/pub/static/
```

what an issue? I have found many solutions but did not work it

thanks!!

Comment: check permission and owner issue.

Comment: @RohanHapani thanks for replay means user owner permission?

Comment: chown of files and folders.

Comment: @RohanHapani yes that permission i see (https://prnt.sc/21cbo5r) , it is not correct?

Comment: are you logged in with that user?

Comment: @RohanHapani i don't know but i am checking in ftp account and whm terminal
which one is correct user set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131972/discussion-between-jaydip-patel-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: You can check file php.ini  find memory_limit how much have you set their limit?

Comment: @nhungoduc https://prnt.sc/21cfb05

Comment: try changing memory_limit  them to 4G or 5G then run the command  php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:upgrade  or php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade @JaydipPatel

Comment: @nhungoduc i have increased memory but still same issue

Comment: @JaydipPatel You can run command  folder  magento 
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Comment: chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: chown -R user_magento:user_magento  *
note user_magento  is the username that can run all commands in the magento folder and has the permission to add and edit checks in the var/log file folder